# Is it possible to modify output data file names in pySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Simplified case.

Given that I have 5 input files in directory `data_directory`:

```
data_2020-01-01.txt,
data_2020-01-02.txt,
data_2020-01-03.txt,
data_2020-01-04.txt,
data_2020-01-05.txt
```

I read them all to pySpark RDD and perform some operation on them that doesn't do any shuffling.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Clean Data").getOrCreate()
sparkContext = spark.sparkContext

input_rdd = sparkContext.textFile("data_directory/*")
result = input_rdd.mapPartitions(lambda x: remove_corrupted_rows(x))
```

Now I want to save data:

```
result.saveAsTextFile(
    "results",
    compressionCodecClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec",
)
```

And I get 5 files where each contains name "part". So I've lost information about from which input file does the output file come from:

```
._SUCCESS.crc
.part-00000.gz.crc
.part-00001.gz.crc
.part-00002.gz.crc
.part-00003.gz.crc
.part-00004.gz.crc
_SUCCESS
part-00000.gz
part-00001.gz
part-00002.gz
part-00003.gz
part-00004.gz
```

**Is there anyway to keep the input file names or introduce my own naming pattern in this case?**

Expected desired result:

```
._SUCCESS.crc
.data_2020-01-01.gz.crc
.data_2020-01-02.gz.crc
.data_2020-01-03.gz.crc
.data_2020-01-04.gz.crc
.data_2020-01-05.crc
_SUCCESS
data_2020-01-01.gz
data_2020-01-02.gz
data_2020-01-03.gz
data_2020-01-04.gz
data_2020-01-05.gz
```

Comment: Your part files aren't guarantee to contain those dates (also not guaranteed to have equal number of output files). You can use named directory partitions if you want to preserve that information

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name()` (docs here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=functions#pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name) and then partition your dataframe by the column created.

This way, 5 input files should give you a categorical column with 5 different values and partitioning on it should split your output into 5 parts.

Alternatively, if you wish to have a full naming pattern, then functionally split the dataframe on the `input_file_name()` column (here into 5 dataframes), repartition (e.g. to 1 using `coalesce(1)`) and then save with custom logic (e.g. a dict mapping or by extracting the filename from the column and parsing to `DataFrameWriter.csv()` as name).

N.B.: When changing to 1 partition, be sure that the data fits all into your memory!